# Java Installation: Cannot Open jvm.cfg at Non-Default Location

Tags: java, installation

Need help on install Java correctly:

I installed Java 11 at first at location: Java Installation:C:\jdk (The new folder I created). I set Java_Home in system variable for this location.

Later I noticed that I need Java 8, I installed at default location:
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201

I delete Java 11 and change the Java Home path to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201.

However, when I run cmd and check java -version, it still point to old location even I have deleted c:\jdk folder.

Error: could not open `C:\jdk\jdk\lib\amd64\jvm.cfg'

System variable and path has been set to new jdk location but Windows still point to old jdk location. How can I change that?

I do javac -version, it returens ok,javac 1.8.0_201
I do echo %JAVA_HOME%, it returns C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201

Just when I do java -version. It gives me above error

Comment: Can you check your PATH system variable again. The path c:\jdk should be removed from PATH. If still doesn't work. Try reopening the command prompt, or restarting the system.

Comment: Resolved after uninstall and reinstall Java